# Visual Studio Community 2015 does not detect my installed windows 10 sdk

Tags: windows

I download an offline installer of windows 10 sdk. But when i open visual studio 2015 and try to create a new windows 10 universal app, i find no templates as well as it says no sdk installed.

Comment: Did you find a solution? I have the same problem.

Comment: I am looking for solution also, I have the same problem